# Windows: how to spawn threads from (NDIS) kernel driver?

Tags: windows, multithreading, reentrancy, ndis

Which function is recommended to spawn a new thread within NDIS5/6 context? Looking for something that is guaranteed to work at IRQL=PASSIVE (e.g. no bsods out of nothing); by a quick examination of `ndis.h` contents, found nothing.

Also, it is planned to use a newly spawned thread for calling upon `NdisFreeMemory*` family, will it be causing any problems to free allocated, but unused memory from a different thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading is outside the scope of NDIS.  If you need to start a new thread, use the standard kernel routines (like `PsCreateSystemThread`).  Note that usually timers and work items are sufficicent for most miniport needs.  It is unusual for an NDIS miniport to create its own thread, although I suppose there are valid cases where it might be a fair design.

It is ok to allocate memory on one thread and free it on another.